# Facebook public post search with API v2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I built an application that uses the public post search feature of Facebook API v1. This API version is supported until April 2015, and I must migrate my application to API v2 before that date.
How can I search for public posts matching a keyword using the v2 API? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

That's simple: It will no longer be possible from April 30th 2015. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_graph_api under the paragraph "Removed endpoints":

> Public post search is no longer available.
>   (/search?type=post&q=foobar)

Comment: ok, but there isn't any other way to do that? I've an application that uses this functionality and I'm looking for another method or workaround in order to do this search...could you anyone help me?

Comment: I don't see a way here, because Facebook apparantly wants to limit the "visibility" of Users by design with this step in my opinion. How should this work in another way if you can't use the search, and don't know the User IDs (which will be app-specific in v2.0 anyway)? End of the road I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at PYLON, an initiative from DataSift. This is the [link](https://datasift.com/products/pylon-for-facebook-topic-data/)
They say that we get access to Public and non-public posts: aggregated and anonymized , Engagement data: comments, likes and shares and Links and hashtag.

But this will have its own subscription model.